# VS2013 and CUDA 12 compatibility

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cuda, 3d-reconstruction

> Error 2   error MSB3721: The command ""C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\bin\nvcc.exe" -gencode=arch=compute_35,code="sm_35,compute_35" --use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64" -x cu -rdc=true  -IInclude\cutil\inc -IC:\Users\fardin\BundleFusion2\BundleFusion\FriedLiver -ISource\DXUT\Optional -ISource\DXUT\Core -IInclude\Uplink -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel RealSense SDK 2.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel RealSense SDK 2.0\third-party\" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\include"     --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=62  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -DWIN32 -D_DEBUG -DDEBUG -DPROFILE -D_CONSOLE -DD3DXFX_LARGEADDRESS_HANDLE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DNOMINMAX -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /Fdx64\Debug\vc120.pdb /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -o C:\Users\fardin\BundleFusion2\BundleFusion\FriedLiver\x64\Debug\CUDAHistogramHashSDF.cu.obj "C:\Users\fardin\BundleFusion2\BundleFusion\FriedLiver\Source\DepthSensing\CUDAHistogramHashSDF.cu"" exited with code 1.    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations\CUDA 12.0.targets    794 9   FriedLiver

I ran into this issue when I was building my project. So I was wondering whether CUDA 12 is compatible with VS2013. I am on windows 11 so I can only download CUDA 12 and 11.6. Also I have both VS2013 and VS2019 but my project requires it to be used in VS2013

Comment: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#system-requirements

Comment: To quote from above link: "Support for Visual Studio 2015 is deprecated in release 11.1." So support for 2013 has probably been dropped a while ago. The oldest supported version is "Visual Studio 2017 15.x (RTW and all updates)".

Answer (score 1):

CUDA 12 is [not compatible](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#id2) with VS2013.

If you attempt to run the CUDA 12 installer after installing VS2013, the CUDA 12 installer will ignore the VS2013 install, and not install necessary pieces to make the integration work.